# why we use double slash instead http

Tags: javascript, html, http, hyperlink

I see some web pages that link javascript file to page like this :

```
<script async="" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js"></script>
```

Why we use double slash ( // ) instead `http://` or `https://` from beginig absolute url ? what's different ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the protocol will be inherited from whichever page you're on. If your site can be on different protocols - `http` on the homepage, `https` on account pages, for example - then you won't have to worry about potentially loading "insecure content."

Comment: You can use `https` from regular http pages.  Upgrading to https is OK, its downgrading that give the warning/error.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - right. The main concern would be loading `http` over `https`

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that by not specifying a particular protocol, the script will load using the same protocol used to load the page itself. This has advantages when the page is accessible through more than one protocol (e.g., both `http:` and `https:`).

For more information see [RFC 3986, Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-30): Relative Resolution of URIs.